# Replace IPython menu icon

Tags: python, windows, icons, wxpython, ipython

I'm using Anaconda Python 2.7 and [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) (wxPython wrapper) to create a simple, interactive GUI in Windows 7. When I run my code, the GUI pops up and the IPython icon is shown on the menu bar.

[image]

I'd like to replace this icon with one of my own. I've tracked down the file to

```
C:\Anaconda2\info\recipe\IPython.ico
```

which I've replaced with my own .ico file. But despite the replacement, the IPython icon remains. I've tried restarting the computer, as well as replacing with verified valid .ico files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my knowledge on all of this is slim, but my guess would be that the image must also be stored somewhere else. If this is not in a file (as I guess you have already searched for those), then this could mean that the .ico file you found might have been translated into a base64 python image. I personally use wxPythons [img2py](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/tools/img2py.py) to achieve such a thing. Maybe Gooey uses this as well? You should be able to find the base64 code in some of your projects .py files. My guess would be images.py.

If you would change it with the base64 code of another ico file that can be generated (for example) by img2py you might be up for a winner.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Gooey [documentation](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey#customizing-icons):

## Customizing Icons

Gooey comes with a set of six default icons. These can be overridden with your own custom images/icons by telling Gooey to search additional directories when initializing. This is done via the image_dir argument to the Goeey decorator.

```
@Gooey(program_name='Custom icon demo', image_dir='/path/to/my/image/directory')
def main():
    # rest of program
```

Images are discovered by Gooey based on their filenames. So, for example, in order to supply a custom configuration icon, simply place an image with the filename config_icon.png in your images directory. These are the filenames which can be overridden:

- program_icon.ico
- success_icon.png
- running_icon.png
- loading_icon.gif
- config_icon.png
- error_icon.png

Comment: It's a good idea but unfortunately this folder doesn't contain the IPython icon --> https://i.imgur.com/uXSV7Gm.png